# What do I need to do to get my callback function to run before other things?

Tags: javascript, json

So in a js file I have this:

```
if(players[i].src.indexOf("http:\/\/vimeo.com/moogaloop") == 0){
    var videoId = players[i].src.split("clip_id=")[1].substring(0, 8);

    var callback = 'getThumb';
    var jsonUrl = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + videoId + '.json?callback=' + callback;

    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    js.setAttribute('src', jsonUrl);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(js);

    var thumb;
    function getThumb(video) {
    thumb = video[0].thumbnail_medium;

    }
```

The purpose is to get the thumbnail of the vimeo video. The problem I am having is that it runs through and does the stuff after it and THEN runs the function. The issue with that is I need the thumbnail to actually do the stuff after it, so it tries to do it with an undefined variable. Everything works otherwise, meaning if it ran in the order I wanted it to, it would work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put any code that needs to run after the code in your callback actually in your callback, rather than merely after it in the file.

Comment: Is that the only thing you can do? I suppose perhaps I simply can't use it then, but it isn't really feasible to put everything in there, even when not considering that the code up there could potentially be run several times.

Comment: A lot of Javascript programming ends up being about callbacks, so it's important to learn to work with them. You could put the code you want to run in another function, and call that at the end of your callback, but that's effectively the same thing. It's unlikely to be true that "it isn't really feasible to put everything in there", but you may have to get creative with your program structure in order to have things work.